# Need more precision from fprintf - Matlab

Tags: matlab

M-File

```
fprintf('\n\nn!\n')
for i=[1:length(timearray)]
    fprintf('%s \t %d \n', stringarray{i},factorial(timearray(i)))
end
```

Output

```
n!
microsecond      1 
minute       Inf 
hour         Inf 
day          Inf 
month        Inf 
year         Inf 
century      Inf
```

I'm trying to calculate the number of steps an algorithm that runs at n! takes at the above intervals (assuming 1 step = 1 microsecond). However, I am unable to get `fprintf` to display meaningful results.

Switching to `fprintf('%s \t %bu \n', stringarray{i},factorial(timearray(i)))` gave me some numbers, but I suspect they are wrong.

%bu Output

```
n!
microsecond      04607182418800017408 
minute       09218868437227405312 
hour         09218868437227405312 
day          09218868437227405312 
month        09218868437227405312 
year         09218868437227405312 
century      09218868437227405312
```

*Disclaimer*: I wrote this program to solve a homework problem, however the homework never specified to write a program.

Thanks for any help!

Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is likely not with printing per se, but that the factorial computation itself is overflowing. Try just evaluating the value instead of printing it in the loop; you'll find that the factorial function overflows after 170!.

One simple way to circumvent this is by returning the log-factorial instead:

```
log_factorial = @(n) sum(log(1:n));
```

Then you can compare values on vastly different scales without worrying about overflow. Note: the above function is not vectorized so it will only work with a single value input; if you need to work with array values then there appear to be [other solutions](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14920) already available.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using the "other solution" you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Matlab probably has 64 bit integers and that number is the largest that factorial could fit into it before the integer ran out of room. I don't have Matlab so can't test it out, but just stop and think about how big a number factorial(century) is going to be...